# Suffix vue data to class with v-bind

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following template within a Vue Multiselect component.

```
<template slot="option" scope="props">
  <div class="option__desc">
    <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{ props.option.code }}">{{ props.option.code }}</span>
    <span class="option__small">{{ props.option.name }}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

I need to suffix `props.option.code` to the `flag-icon-` class but Vue does not allow me to add to the class this way anymore. It requires me to do it with `v-bind` however I've tried to make it work with `v-bind` and I cannot.

Is there a way to make this work with `v-bind`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<span :class="'flag-icon flag-icon-' + props.option.code">
```

Comment: Thanks that's it :)